# Processing cube -Error-A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: ssas, mdx, device, cube

I trying to process the first MDX cube. I have an error while trying to process the cube- "A device attached to the system is not functioning"

i have tried the following
a) The folder am saving my project i have full control of that folder.
b) On Device manager, all drivers are update. No yellow question marks.
c) Am on window 10 - 64 bit machine.

Kindly assist

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to the locale of the account running your SQLServer service and Analsyis Services service.
You can change the locale using the registry editor, and restart the server.
Use pstools psgetsid to get the SID of your the SQLServer and Analysis Services service account:

```
psgetsid "NT Service\MSSQL$SQL"
psgetsid "NT Service\MSOLAP$SQL"
```

Got to registry key Computer\HKEY_USERS\\Control Panel\International and update the Locale and LocaleName.
Locale = 00000409 and LocaleName = en-US

Restart the server for this registry setting change to become active.
Processing will now work (you might have to redeploy the SSAS solution).

Comment: Thanks. This has worked. Kenyan New developers are happy lot.

Comment: @Mattias can you please elaborate on the solution? or a link...PS I am another David

Comment: @Mattias. I serached for regedit in windows and went to the directory HKEY_USERS... and changed Locale and LocaleName and it seems to work. I still have other errors but "A device attached to the system is not functioning" is now gone. But what do the `psgetsid` commands do?

Comment: Hi, you need the SID to find the correct registry entry. I described in detail here : https://www.mattiasdesmet.be/2020/06/16/ssas-locale-error-while-processing-cube/